# Magento gallery images shown in backend, but not on frontend?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images

I created a product by code and also set the main image and the gallery images with code. When I check the product in the backend, all images are there.

On the frontend, it only shows the main image, the gallery images are not shown. So I checked the `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` table for my product and it has ALL the gallery images I want.

So they are imported to the right place, but not shown on frontend. I tried uploading another gallery image manually from the backend, this works, it shows up on frontend. Just the ones being imported by code do not show up.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: can you share your code???

Comment: Do you see placeholder images? Did you try to debug the gallery?

Comment: Did you try reindexing or save again the imported product from admin?